# Why my rails app shows nested table's id but nested column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

The view shows okay with this code

```
<%= community.country_id %>
```

---

```
<%= community.country.name %>
```

but this gives error back

> 'Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'countries.community_id' in 'where
>   clause': SELECT  `countries`.* FROM `countries`  WHERE
>   `countries`.`community_id` = 5 LIMIT 1'

My models are

community.rb

```
has_one :country
```

country.rb

```
belongs_to :community
```

Comment: Is it because I also have has_many :communities in User.rb model, and belongs_to :user in communities.rb model?? Is it messing up association??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Country` model, if you have a relation like

```
has_one :country
```

by default, Rails will look for a column in the `countries` table in your database called `community_id`.

The error you're getting is saying you never migrated such a column into your database. Run the following from your shell to add that column.

```
rails generate migration AddCommunityIdToCountries community_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

**Recommended Reading** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm trying to communities model, and it has country_id.   country_id judges what country the community is about. Consider if the user want to make socccer community about England, community table's country_id will be set as england's id.

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand you.

Comment: sorry about that. For example, I have user model and user_profile model. They are associated as one-to-one.  In 'user model' it has has_one :user_profile, then user_profile model has belongs_to :user. I just want to make association like this. each community has one country. each country belongs to one community.  Then I was coding <%= community.country.name %> to show its country

Comment: When you say `community.country.name`, for the given `Community`, it is going to query the `countries` table for the `Country` having a `:community_id` value matching the `:id` of `community`. The error in your Question says you do not have a `community_id` column in the `countries` table. I am showing you how to add that, giving Rails what it needs to make the association.

Comment: Oh yeah!! You're right!! in the case between user and user_profile. That's one-to-one. But in this community-country case, do I probably need to middle table between them???? In the case of having master table, are we supposed to make middle table between transaction table and master table??

Comment: I have no idea; I don't know what you're eventual goal is with these models. Right now `Community` and `Country` are in a `1-1` relationship with each other. If you have different intentions, I suggest reading the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on associations. Regardless, that's all outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks!! I was doing opposite. community belongs to country, and country has one community